# Cannot change delimiter of output csv for es2csv cli

Tags: csv, elasticsearch

Could you please suggest what i am doing wrong? i cannot change the delimiter of the output file using es2csv cli tool.

```
es2csv -q '*'  -i test_index -o test.csv -f id name -d /t
```

Comment: output separator is still using comma. also quoting string could work for me, but i could not find an option for that

Comment: Have you tried `-d '\t'` ?

Comment: yeah tried a lot of option, with different separators always gives back comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this issue has been reported here: https://github.com/taraslayshchuk/es2csv/issues/51

If you don't want to wait for the fix to be released, you can change line 212 of `es2csv.py` like this and it will work:

```
csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=self.csv_headers, delimiter=unicode(self.opts.delimiter))
```

Comment: thanks working, although still faces some issues with tab but other delimiters are working already